# What is the stone structure that Frodo and Sam are sleeping in?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

At the very beginning of The Return of the King (film) Frodo and Sam are awakened by Smeagol/Gollum after sleeping in a diamond-shaped stone structure of some kind. I feel like this place has a name, but it's been a while since I've read the books. Reading [this online script of the movie](http://www.ageofthering.com/atthemovies/scripts/returnoftheking1to4.php), it is only referred to (Scene 2, Journey to the Cross-roads) as a "concrete culvert".

Does this place have a name? Who likely built it?

Comment: It's been a while since I watched the movies, but I'm currently reading the books. I have a feeling that, as John Rennie answered, this is unique to the movie, though if you could add a screengrab of what you're talking about that may help.

Comment: Certainly it's not in that position in the book: the first book of RoTK follows Pippin/Merry, and the second book begins with Frodo captured by the Orcs of Cirith Ungol and Sam shut outside.

Comment: It's strange that the script says concrete rather than stone. A stone culvert would fit, but as far as I can recall, concrete doesn't exist in Middle-earth.

Comment: That's not a script, it's a fan-made transcript. The *original* script says nothing about concrete. See below.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's from The Two Towers, chapter 7 - Journey to the Crossroads. The scene in the book is:

> On the further edge of this broad hill-back they stayed their march and crawled for hiding underneath a tangled knot of thorns. Their twisted boughs, stooping to the ground, were overridden by a clambering maze of old briars. Deep inside there was a hollow hall, raftered with dead branch and bramble, and roofed with the first leaves and shoots of spring. There they lay for a while, too tired yet to eat; and peering out through the holes in the covert they watched for the slow growth of day

They stay during the day in the hollow hall, and when night falls Gollum wakens them with *Wake up, wake up! Wake up, sleepies!*.

Assuming I have the correct scene, I'm afraid the hollow hall is not named or even described any further.

Answer (score 3):

The [original script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Lord-of-the-Rings-Return-of-the-King.html) refers to it as a "culvert".

> SETTLE ON: FRODO and SAM in a **FILTHY CULVERT.**. 
>   SAM twitches in a RESTLESS SLEEP. But FRODO is awake . . . His
>   hand trails down to the CHAIN around his NECK ...
>
> A SUDDEN HISS! FRODO quickly hides the RING as GOLLUM peers at them with GLEAMING EYES.

Typically these are used to channel a river or a storm runoff away from a populated area, which explains its construction.

At some point someone who lived there obviously didn't like their farm or homestead or path being flooded out when it rained.